# onActivityResult code for both Facebook and Google+ Login in Android

Tags: android, google-plus

The Facebook API code for login in Android is simple, with the method ***onActivityResult*** is

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The documentation from Google says the code for the same method must be

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult:" + requestCode + ":" + resultCode + ":" + data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // If the error resolution was not successful we should not resolve further.
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mShouldResolve = false;
        }

        mIsResolving = false;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

Assume all variables are declared and initialized. What must the code be for onActivityResult to handle both Facebook and G+ login.

My Login (Activity) code is

```
package cc.campusconnect.devapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;


import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener{

    private static final String TAG = "Login";
    LoginButton btnFBLogin;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    /* Is there a ConnectionResult resolution in progress? */
    private boolean mIsResolving = false;

    /* Should we automatically resolve ConnectionResults when possible? */
    private boolean mShouldResolve = false;

    /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        btnFBLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fblogin);
        btnFBLogin.setReadPermissions("public_profile email");
        btnFBLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                            JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                            try {
                                if (json != null) {
                                    String text = "<b>Name :</b> " + json.getString("name") + "<br><br><b>Email :</b> " + json.getString("email") + "<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> " + json.getString("link");
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .build();
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            onSignInClicked();
        }

    }
    private void onSignInClicked() {
        // User clicked the sign-in button, so begin the sign-in process and automatically
        // attempt to resolve any errors that occur.
        mShouldResolve = true;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        // Show a message to the user that we are signing in.
        System.out.println("Signing in...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // Could not connect to Google Play Services.  The user needs to select an account,
        // grant permissions or resolve an error in order to sign in. Refer to the javadoc for
        // ConnectionResult to see possible error codes.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);

        if (!mIsResolving && mShouldResolve) {
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                    mIsResolving = true;
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not resolve ConnectionResult.", e);
                    mIsResolving = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else {
                // Could not resolve the connection result, show the user an
                // error dialog.
                //showErrorDialog(connectionResult);
                System.out.println("Couldn't connect");
            }
        } else {
            // Show the signed-out UI
            //showSignedOutUI();
            System.out.println("Signed out");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: add codes for both G+ and fb in single onactivity result

Comment: you can add this line `callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` in your onactivityresult for g+

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult:" + requestCode + ":" + resultCode + ":" + data);

if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
    // If the error resolution was not successful we should not resolve further.
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        mShouldResolve = false;
    }

    mIsResolving = false;
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}else{
  //If not request code is RC_SIGN_IN it must be facebook
  callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to include twitter login also. We need one else if here with condition. Do you know how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: just add else if wit request code for twitter or anything else not related to login. Its just how you request and resolve the response based on request code. Thanks

Comment: You can check if callback manager successfully handled result like this: `boolean handled = callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` and if not, then you can approve to if-else.

Comment: @subhash Using the way you mentioned I am able to login but unable to logout from either facebook or google.

Comment: as per new API, `startActivityForResult(..)` is deprecated, so we have to get rid of `onActivityResult()`, so we can't send and get `requestCode`, now look at this image - https://prnt.sc/1wpspcz, do you have knowledge about this problem, then please tell us..